# Why does a "never" return function not narrow down types like throwing does?

Tags: typescript

In the following Typescript snippet, `foo` is correctly narrowed down to be definitely a number after the if check:

```js
declare const foo: number | undefined

if (!foo) { throw new Error() }

foo // const foo: number
```

However when using an error wrapper function the type narrowing doesn't work anymore even when explicitly setting the function return type to never:

```js
const errorWrapper = (): never => { throw new Error() }

declare const bar: number | undefined

if (!bar) { errorWrapper() }

bar // const bar: number | undefined
```

So how do I tell Typescript that `bar` is definitely a number after the if check using the error wrapper?

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPCgK4C2ARiDPAD7zEqjYCWKIwAUB89vABQBCXEgCU8AN7wMACxhIA7kRCKAojDkw+YgL5dh8APQHEqTDjyESFKlwMAqeAFpnL12-cfPXj-DsGuyOhYVBoA6jBQAA6RVPAAvPwiliAAbrFxAHwSUrIKSqrqSJo6XKCQsAiBZuSwlmSU1HQMTKzsXDz8AjUwYpIhReFRMcXwuhzdhsZVWN111o30jCAsbJxAA

Comment: You could make `errorWrapper()` _return_ the exception, allowing you to `throw errorWrapper();`. Then the static analysis would have a much easier time picking up on the change in code flow.

Comment: @Rogue What if there's more logic inside the error wrapper that needs to be run before the error is thrown?

Comment: You're probably looking for [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) or [custom type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: @Susccy the logic would still be run from the call to `errorWrapper()`, it's just that the actual throwing of the exception would happen after the function call. Instead of `throw ...` in the function, you'd have `return ...`.

Comment: Because static code analysis doesn't step into function calls to check whether they throw unconditionally or not. As far as static code analysis is concerned, `errorWrapper()`  is just a call to an arbitrary function, that doesn't narrow the type of `bar` ...

Comment: @derpirscher then what's the point of the `never` return type on a function?

Comment: It indicates that you never `return` from the function, either through a return value or normal completion without a returned value (a `void` return type and `return;`, implicit or not). Examples are always throwing an exception (through `throw`) or never reaching the end of the method (a la `while (true) { ... }`). It indicates that you should not expect a function call to simply return invocation to you after being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript does support [treating `never`-returning functions as affecting control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#better-support-for-never-returning-functions); this support has the same benefits and drawbacks as those of [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), as both were implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695).  One important drawback is that you need to make sure that such functions have **"explicit types"**:

> A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning call when
>
> - the call occurs as a top-level expression statement, and
> - the call specifies a single identifier or a dotted sequence of identifiers for the function name, and
> - each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type, and
> - the function name resolves to a function type with an `asserts` return type or an explicit `never` return type annotation.
>
> An entity is considered to have an explicit type when it is declared as a function, method, class or namespace, or as a variable, parameter or property with an explicit type annotation. (This particular rule exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls doesn't circularly trigger further analysis.)

In your case, `const errorWrapper = (): never => { throw new Error() }` does not count as `errorWrapper` having an explicit type.  The value *assigned* to `errorWrapper` is explicitly typed, but then you're asking the compiler to *infer* the type of `errorWrapper` from it, since it is not annotated (nothing between `const errorWrapper` and `=`).  This breaks the rule, so it's not given the control-flow powers you want.

**The easiest fix here is to move the annotation onto `errorWrapper` itself:**

```
const errorWrapper: () => never = () => { throw new Error() }
```

Now `errorWrapper` is explicitly of type `() => never` and things start working as you expect:

```
declare const bar: number | undefined   
if (!bar) { errorWrapper() }   
bar // const bar: number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPCgK4C2ARiDPAD7zEqjYCWKIwAUB89vABQBCXEgCU8AN7wMACxhIA7kRCKAojDkw+YgL5dh8APQHEqTDjyESFKlwMAqeAFpnL12-cfPXj-DsGuyOhYVBoA6jBQAA6RVIRa8AC8AHxKAG5UifxiyRJSsgpKqupImjpcoJCwCIFm5LCWZJTUdAxMrOxcPPwCdTBikiEl4VExpfC6HL2GxjVYvQ3WMBxAA)

Comment: And a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) can be used for slightly more compact syntax: https://tsplay.dev/NnLyBW

Comment: I like this answer, but man typescript makes that annotated `errorWrapper` line quite a garble to read.